# Django model class perfix models_

Tags: django, django-models

I was designed two model classes and run manage.py syncdb to create tables into my database.

```
class ADMMC(models.Model):
MC001 = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)    
MC002 = models.CharField(max_length=20)                    
CreateDate = models.DateTimeField()
UpdateDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class ADMMD(models.Model):
MD001 = models.CharField(max_length=8)
MD002 = models.CharField(max_length=5, primary_key=True)   
MD003 = models.CharField(max_length=10)                     
CreateDate = models.DateTimeField()
UpdateDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

> python manage.py syncdb

However, When I open the database management tool and look those tables, those tables are auto join **"models_"** in front of the table.

Does anyone know how to remove **models_**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the [`db_table` Meta option](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table).

Comment: Thank you guy, My problem was solved. Django will auto joining the model's "app label" to table name. so I can set db_table to custom table name.

Answer (score 0):

Django prepends your app name to the table name. In your case, Django is guessing that "models" is your app name. That probably has to do with the module structure you defined. Could you provide more details on your files and modules?

A typical structure would be:

```
 - my_app
     +-- __init__.py
     +-- models.py
     +-- views.py
```

Where Django will guess from my_app.models module that your app is called "my_app" and name your tables "my_app_ADMMC" etc.